# Loading osmdroid tiles from multiple zip files

Tags: android, google-maps, zip, osmdroid

Can I make osmdroid to load tiles from multiple zip files?
I have multiple cities that I want to load tiles for them and for each one there is a zip file. My code only gets one name for zip file and obviously we can't multiple files with the same name.
Also the user must not do anything special to load tiles. only by moving map to certain location. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several zip files (each with a separate name) in my osmdroid folder. They all provide the map data automatically when the location's longitude and latitude correspond to a place within any of the zip files. I don't know how it works, but it does!